# Changing list in dictionary changes all lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have read these posts here explaining exactly the problem I am having, but none of the solutions are working:

[Changing one list unexpectedly changes another, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785084/changing-one-list-unexpectedly-changes-another-too)

[Changing One dict value changes all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498453/changing-one-dict-value-changes-all-values)

I have a specific shape of 2D array I need to initialize the entries in a dictionary with. Here is how I have done it:

```
empty = []
for x in range(2):
    empty.append([])
    for y in range(2):
        empty[x].append(False)

status = {k:[] for k in ["a", "b", "c"]}

status["a"] = list(empty)
status["b"] = list(empty)
status["c"] = list(empty)

print(status)
status["a"][0][0] = True
print(status)
```

(Shape of list simplified for example)

This prints:

```
{'a': [[False, False], [False, False]], 'b': [[False, False], [False, False]], 'c': [[False, False], [False, False]]}
{'a': [[True, False], [False, False]], 'b': [[True, False], [False, False]], 'c': [[True, False], [False, False]]}
```

As you can see, setting one of the lists values changes all of the lists. I do not want this, I want them to be separate lists (in one dictionary) with different values.

Initially, I thought I had done the old `newlist = oldlist` blunder where I set newlist to the same object as oldlist, but nope. As you can see in my code, I am making separate lists using `newlist = list(oldlist)`. I have also tried `newlist = oldlist[:]`, `newlist = oldlist.copy()`, etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess you've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly ?`list(empty)` _does_ create a new list, but the inner lists of that new list are just references to the same list objects in `empty`.

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from copy import deepcopy
empty = []
for x in range(2):
    empty.append([])
    for y in range(2):
        empty[x].append(False)

status = {k:[] for k in ["a", "b", "c"]}

status["a"] = deepcopy(empty)
status["b"] = deepcopy(empty)
status["c"] = deepcopy(empty)

print(status)
status["a"][0][0] = True
print(status)
```

you were close with the copy, but you actually neeed a deepcopy

Comment: Exactly what I needed! It works! I didn't realize the INNER lists were the same object, too!

Answer (score 3):

As I said earlier, `list(empty)` *does* create a new list, but the inner lists of that new list are just references to the same list objects in `empty`.

You *can* use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), but I think it's simpler just to build new lists when you need them. The `deepcopy` function jumps through various hoops that are required to copy arbitrarily deep nested objects that can contain anything. But why bother going through all that stuff when you have a structure that's simple to just build from scratch?

Using a list comprehension, your code can be written like this:

```
status["a"] = [[False] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
status["b"] = [[False] * 2 for _ in range(2)]
#etc
```

It's safe to do `[False] * 2` for the innermost lists: it's always safe to share immutable objects (booleans, integers, strings, etc). The problem only arises when you unexpectedly share a mutatable object and you mutate its value instead of replacing it with a new object.

To avoid re-writing that list comp, you can use a function to build the lists for you. Eg,

```
def empty(rows, columns):
    return [[False] * columns for _ in range(rows)]

status = {key: empty(2, 2) for key in 'abc'}
print(status)
status["a"][0][0] = True
print(status)
```

**output**

```
{'a': [[False, False], [False, False]], 'b': [[False, False], [False, False]], 'c': [[False, False], [False, False]]}
{'a': [[True, False], [False, False]], 'b': [[False, False], [False, False]], 'c': [[False, False], [False, False]]}
```

Comment: Totally agree.  I believe `deepcopy` is overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the first element of your `empty` list is shared across all the values in your dictionary:

```
>>> id(empty[0]) == id(status['a'][0]) == id(status['b'][0]) == id(status['c'][0])
True
```

They each share the same memory location.  The same is also true for the second item in the empty list, `id(empty[1]) == id(status['a'][1]) == ...`

The reason for this is your assignment of your `empty` list to each value.  You can either perform a deep copy this empty, nested list, or else use a list comprehension to generate new ones for each key in your dictionary.  This list comprehension for the empty list creation is itself done within a dictionary comprehension to generate your `status` variable for all the required keys.

```
empty_rows = 2
empty_cols = 2
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
status = {k: [[False] * empty_cols 
              for _ in range(empty_rows)] 
          for k in keys}

# Example usage:
status['a'][0][0] = True
>>> status
{'a': [[True, False], [False, False]],
 'b': [[False, False], [False, False]],
 'c': [[False, False], [False, False]]}
```

Now you can change any element without it affecting the others.

Comment: +1 for the `id()` function. I would recommend to the OP to really play around with it and understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a deep copy, see documentation of [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

```
import copy
empty = []
for x in range(2):
    empty.append([])
    for y in range(2):
        empty[x].append(False)

status = {k:[] for k in ["a", "b", "c"]}

status["a"] = copy.deepcopy(empty)
status["b"] = copy.deepcopy(empty) 
status["c"] = copy.deepcopy(empty)
status['a'][0][0] = True
print(status)
```

Comment: hey, it is not different, I was typing the answer, got busy with other things, and when submitted the previous answers were already there ... (perhaps, the only thing is that I had added a reference to the python docs)