# Why is the a.insert() function affection another list b?

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a small piece of code and im trying to understand from past 3 hours, im getting Nowhere:

```
n =10
for i in range(3):
    a .insert(0,n+i)
    print('A =>',a)
    b.append(a)
    print('B=>', b)
```

The Output of the following code is :

```
A => [10]
B=> [[10]]
A => [11, 10]
B=> [[11, 10], [11, 10]]
A => [12, 11, 10]
B=> [[12, 11, 10], [12, 11, 10], [12, 11, 10]]
```

My Confusion is, when i'm inserting a new element in list a  , and then appending the new list a to the old list b, why are the previous values getting overridden??? I cant understand , what is happening here

Comment: Hello PyCoder you can also have a look at this :) this is similar to the reason why that is happening [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642538/python-changing-list-in-dictionary-changes-all-lists-no-other-solutions-working/52642675)

Comment: You keep appending *the same list* to `b`

Comment: Note, this behavior isn't unique to lists, **all objects work this way** when you `.append` them to a list

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way python copies lists.
When you do `b.append(a)` you are actually appending the *reference of* `a`, so when you change any value of `a` it will also change `b`:

Simplified depiction of what's happening:

```
# a = [] -> id_123 
# b = [] -> id_321 

a.insert(0,10)
# a = [10] --> id_123

b.append(a)
# b = [id123] = [[10]] --> id_321

a.insert(0,11)
# a = [10,11] --> id_123

b.append(a)
# b = [id123,id123] = [[10,11],[10,11]] --> id_321
```

In the end:

```
A => [12, 11, 10] --> id_123
B => [[12, 11, 10], [12, 11, 10], [12, 11, 10]] --> id_321
```

In the comments you have explained that you tried:

```
print(a is b)
# prints False
```

However, trying: `a is b[0]` will give the expected result(`True`):

```
for e in b:
    print(a is e)

#prints True 3 times
```

Finally, if you were aiming to instead obtain:

```
A => [10]
B=> [[10]]
A => [11, 10]
B=> [[10], [11, 10]]
A => [12, 11, 10]
B=> [[10], [11, 10], [12, 11, 10]]
```

Then, you can simply change the appending to `b` to:

```
b.append(a[:])
```

Here is a reference form another question here on SO:
From [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent):

> With new_list = my_list, you don't actually have two lists. The assignment just copies the reference to the list, not the actual list, so both new_list and my_list refer to the same list after the assignment.

#### Full code:

```
a=[]
b=[]
n =10
for i in range(3):
    a .insert(0,n+i)
    print('A =>',a)
    b.append(a[:])
    print('B=>', b)
```

Comment: If you are going to post a link to another answer, you should vote to close as a duplicate next time.

Comment: I can´t vote to close with my level of reputation. Instead I thought it would be cool to nudge the OP in the right direction while providing a link to useful information, and relating this to the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

By appending a to b, you do not copy the object, but create a bindings between a and b. Since the list is mutable, you need a deepcopy, so you can change one without changing another.

```
import copy
n =10
b=[]
a = []
for i in range(3):
    a.insert(0,n+i)
    print('A =>',a)
    b.append(copy.deepcopy(a))
    print('B=>', b)
```

Comment: hi MrLukas, so do u mean that both of the variables a and b are pointing to the same object??   But i even tried print(a is b)  and it returned false, which means these object's are not same. isn't it?

Comment: You actually **do not need a deep copy here**

Comment: @PyCoder no. The list being referred to by `b` contains multiple references to the list being referred to by `a`.

Comment: im sorry junapa.arrivillaga , can you explain it in a little more??

Comment: You have a list `a = [1, 2]`, let's say. You have another list, `b = []` You then do `b.append(a)`. Now **the second list contains the first list**. So obviously, if you mutate the first list, `a.append(3)` and then `print(a)` you see `[1,2,3]` but of course, since the second list *contains the first list* you see the same thing in the second list.   Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html