# How to correctly update the values of list types in a Python nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The case is that I'd like to build a nested dictionary with the structure like the following

```
{'a': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []},
 'b': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []},
 'c': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}}
```

and the initiation part is

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
subkeys = ['1','2','3','4']
target_dict = dict.fromkeys(keys, {key: [] for key in subkeys})
```

and then, I want to update the values of a subkey, like `target_dict['a']['1'] = 1`, which i only want to set the entry "a-1" to 1, and leave other values blank. However, the "a-1", "b-1", and "c-1" all update simultaneously. Leading to the result as

```
{'a': {'1': 1, '2': [], '3': [], '4': []},
 'b': {'1': 1, '2': [], '3': [], '4': []},
 'c': {'1': 1, '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}}
```

what's the reason of this case, and how should I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing list in dictionary changes all lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642538/changing-list-in-dictionary-changes-all-lists)

Comment: Basically, don't use mutable objects with `dict.fromkeys()`

Comment: Consider reading about the `defaultdict` from the `collections` module in the standard library. It might help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `target_dict['a']` `target_dict['b']` and `target_dict['c']` seems to be keeping the same reference. Try changing your code to

```python
target_dict = {k: {key: [] for key in subkeys} for k in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're giving each key the same object (a dict) as a value.  Regardless of which key you use to access the dict and modify it, there's only one dict, so it's reflected for all the other keys.

Creating a dict for each key solves the problem:

```
>>> keys = ['a','b','c']
>>> subkeys = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> target_dict = {key: {subkey: [] for subkey in subkeys} for key in keys}
>>> target_dict
{'a': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}, 'b': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}, 'c': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}}
>>> target_dict['a']['1'].append(1)
>>> target_dict
{'a': {'1': [1], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}, 'b': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}, 'c': {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': []}}
```