# Populating nested dictionary by iterating over dataframe not producing desired result

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, time-series

I have a dataframe with double timestamped data (effective date and termination date), and I want to produce a nested dictionary (and ultimately a new dataframe) for each entity represented in the data that counts the active instances of the data over time. For example, if a field becomes active in 1980, I want the value for that company key in the 1980 key to increase by 1. If a field terminates in 1992, I want the value for that company key in the 1992 key to decrease by 1.

Here is an example of the data:

```
ID  CO_Num  CO_Name      Termination_Date   Effective_Date
106072  84028   COMPANY A    7/1/04         4/9/69
106084  84028   COMPANY A    12/1/85            8/20/69
106094  84028   COMPANY A    12/1/70            10/3/69
106115  84028   COMPANY B    12/1/85            1/7/70
106133  91108   COMPANY B    2/4/86         3/6/70
106133  91108   COMPANY C    NaT                3/6/91
106133  91108   COMPANY C    NaT                3/6/91
```

I created a nested dictionary with the year as the top key and the company/instance dictionary as the value, with all company values set at 0. E.g.

```
nest_dict = {2000: {'COMPANY A': 0, 'COMPANY B': 0}, 2001: {'COMPANY A': 0, 'COMPANY B': 0}}
```

Then, I have tried just about every way I can think of to iterate over the dataframe and/or dictionary to get the output that I would like. Here is my current iteration code.

```
for key, value in nest_dict.items():
    for data in df.values:
        if data[4].year == key:
            value[data[2]] += 1
        if data[3].year == key:
            value[data[2]] -= 1
```

When I put the output into a dataframe, it looks like this:

```
           | 1969     | 1970     | 1971     |
 --------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
 Company A | 0        | 0        | 0        |
 Company B | 0        | 0        | 0        |
 Company C | 2        | 2        | 2        |
```

What I want to see is something like this:

```
           | 1969     | 1970     | 1971     |
 --------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
 Company A | 3        | 2        | 2        |
 Company B | 0        | 2        | 2        |
 Company C | 0        | 0        | 0        |
```

In this case, each column is a running tally of active instances for each company. Instead, I am getting all the same terminal value for every company.

I feel like I am missing something very simple here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My first issue was failing to make copies of the company sub-dictionary for each separate year. For more information on this, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642538/changing-list-in-dictionary-changes-all-lists)

My second issues was figuring out how to utilize my previous iteration output values

```
for yr in timeseries:
    if yr == 1969:
        for row in df.values:
            if row[4].year == yr:
                timeseries[yr][row[2]] += 1
            if row[3].year == yr:
                timeseries[yr][row[2]] -= 1

    elif yr > 1969:
        timeseries[yr].update(timeseries[yr - 1])
        for row in df.values:
            if row[4].year == y:
                timeseries[yr][row[2]] += 1
            if row[3].year == yr:
                timeseries[yr][row[2]] -= 1

df1 = pd.DataFrame(timeseries)
df1.index.name = "Company"
```

The numerical indexing of the values calls the 'Effective Date' and 'Termination Date' values from the dataframe row, apologies if it's a bit messy to read.

This gave me the desired result.

```
    1969    1970    1971    1972    1973    1974    1975    1976    1977    1978    1979    1980    1981    1982    1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996
Company                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
COMPANY A   3   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
COMPANY B   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
COMPANY C   0   1   1   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   5   6   12  17  21  21  22  21  20  20  20  20  20  20  20  18  18  16  14  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
COMPANY D   0   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
COMPANY E   0   0   1   2   2   4   4   7   11  16  17  19  25  25  17  17  17  17  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If anyone has comments or suggestions on how to do this better/more efficiently, I would appreciate it.