# Changing the value in one key changes the values in all keys in a dictionary of sets created using fromkeys()

Tags: python, dictionary

I am initializing a sequence like this

```
seq = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
```

Now I am using fromkeys() to convert sequence to dict of sets. here is what I am doing:

```
val = set()
seq_dict =  dict.fromkeys(seq, val)
```

Now it seems if add an element to only one of my dictionary keys set, that element is being added to all the other sets. Here is the example:

```
seq_dict['a'].add("val1")
print(seq_dict)
{'d': {'val1'}, 'c': {'val1'}, 'b': {'val1'}, 'a': {'val1'}, 'e': {'val1'}}
```

Not sure if I am using the fromkeys in a right way though?

Comment: You’ve assigned the same set to all keys. If that wasn’t the intention, use a dict comprehension to initialize the dict.

Comment: Similar, but not an exact duplicate: [Changing one dict value changes all values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13498453/843953)

Comment: @enke True that was not my intention. Would it be possible to give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Here's documentation on a "[set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)" which is the way to fix the problem — and very similar to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps) so I am going to close your question as a dup. It also means you can't use the `fromkeys()` method.

Answer (score 5):

The `fromkeys` method is working as expected, since you have the correct result: a dictionary with keys that are the characters in `seq` variable, and each value that is an empty set.

Your issue is due to mutability of the value you assigned: you assigned an empty set as value for all keywords. If you change this (`seq_dict['a'].add("val1")`), then the values for all keywords are changed (each keyword references the original empty set).

You may want to use dictionary comprehension (which creates a new different copy of the empty set for each key) to avoid this issue:

```
seq = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
seq_dict = {key: set() for key in seq}
```

Comment: Actually this is a working answer, the simplest one, I'll add a couple of link. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
val = set()
seq_dict =  dict.fromkeys(seq, val)
```

You are initializing the `seq_dict` with the same `set` (a **[`mutable`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set)** `type`), so editing `seq_dict['a']` you are editing the same `set` which is the value of all the other keys.

---

If you don't want this to happen, you'll have to initialize the `dict`ionary in an other way.

```
>>> d = {i: set() for i in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')}
>>> d
{'a': set(), 'b': set(), 'c': set(), 'd': set(), 'e': set()}
>>> d['a']
set()
>>> d['a'].add('ehi')
>>> d
{'a': {'ehi'}, 'b': set(), 'c': set(), 'd': set(), 'e': set()}
```

---

So, in other words, you have to *"isolate"* the **`immutable`**s parts of the `set`:

```
seq = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}
seq_dict = {key: set() for key in seq}
```

Comment: Thanks! What would you suggest to fix it?