# Problem in updating a dictionary: all the keys have the same list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am facing a problem in assigning values to dictionary. I want a changing list (which is being updated by every iteration of a loop) assigned to the keys of my dictionary by using a for loop. But the problem is the lists are eventually same for all of the keys.

Let me show it with example:

```
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr']  # this is the list of keys of the Dictionary
numbers = []
sqrDict = {}
i = 1
for m in months:
    numbers.append(i**2)
    sqrDict[m] = numbers
    i += 1

print('sqrDict =', sqrDict)
```

I actually want my dictionary to be as:

```
sqrDict = {'jan': [1], 'feb': [1, 4], 'mar': [1, 4, 9], 'apr': [1, 4, 9, 16]}
```

But what I am having is:

```
sqrDict = {'jan': [1, 4, 9, 16], 'feb': [1, 4, 9, 16], 'mar': [1, 4, 9, 16], 'apr': [1, 4, 9, 16]}
```

I don't understand what the problem is. What is going wrong with my code?

Comment: What's wrong with your code is already a part of your title: all keys have the same list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498453/changing-one-dict-value-changes-all-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue are having is that you are setting `sqrDict[m] = numbers`. At the end, all the values in the dict point to `numbers`. This should fix your code, as it assigns each position in sqrDict to the **value** of numbers at the time, instead of pointing to it, which is achieved by changing `numbers[] to numbers[:]` as shown below:

```
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr'] #this is the list of keys of the Dictionary
numbers = []
sqrDict = {}
i = 1
for m in months:
    numbers.append(i**2)
    sqrDict[m] = numbers[:]
    i += 1

print('sqrDict = ',sqrDict)
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 updated answer to explain!

Comment: _"assigns each position in sqrDict to the value of numbers"_ a more correct way to say this would be that it copies `numbers` and creates a new list that is assigned to that key